# Pass Argument to the dependent function - @depends annotation

Tags: php, phpunit

How do i pass the arguments  to the testone function using @depends annotation. Tried the below way its not workingHow do i pass the arguments  to the testone function. Tried the below way its not working

```
  class MyTest  extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase  {

        public function testOne($xxx)
        {
            echo "value of p1:" . $xxx . "\n";
           // $this->assertTrue(F);
        }

        /**
         * @depends testOne
         * @args xxx
         */
        public function testTwo()
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Return values from testOne. These values will be arguments of testTwo.

Comment: Thanks. want to pass the argument to the first function